# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k g(x-r_k) \not\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> **Problem.**  Let $$g(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} &x\in(0,1)\\0 &\text{Otherwise} \end{cases}$$ And let $\{r_k, k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be enumeration of rational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{a_k\}\subset (0,\infty)$ be a sequence such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k<\infty$$. Accepting the fact that $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k g(x-r_k)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, **prove that** $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k g(x-r_k)\not\in L^2([a,b])\hspace{5mm} \text{for any $a,b$ with } -\infty<a<b<\infty$$

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Choose $r_k\in (a,b)$. Show that $g(x-r_k)\notin L^2[a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you . But even if we show that $g(x-r_k)\not\in L^{2}([a,b])$, the infinite sum can be in $L^2$ since $L^2$ is closed space I think.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1056912)

Comment: @LevBan $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kg(x-r_k)\ge a_kg(x-r_k)>0$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Thanks